# stop execution till the page load OR some time (ms) in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am a beginner in Xamarin and learning to write test using NUnit framework. I am testing an app where am getting some problems in writing test cases some of them i solved but i need some help in solving other issues that am facing. Referring the official Xamarin documentation and learning the scripts but i am not able to find solution for the below issues.

1. When i use repl() and tree method for a screen of the app not able to get the elements where as if i use uiautomatorviewver then am getting all the elements in the screen. so to tap these elements i used TapCoordinates method to click on the elements and its working fine.
   My question is why am not getting the elements in UI if i use repl and tree commands?
   If we use tapcoordinates Is the script works for scalability i.e for the other screen sizes? If its not works for other screen sizes then how to solve this problem?
2. I have script that has to wait for some time before executing a command Is there any method to stop execution till some Micro Seconds?

   //Click on Next buttons available at first four pages

   app.TapCoordinates(752, 1650);

   app.TapCoordinates(752, 1650);

   app.TapCoordinates(752, 1650);

   app.TapCoordinates(752, 1650);

   //Click on Launch Button to move to I agree checkbox

   app.TapCoordinates(752, 1650);

   // Click I agree button

   app.TapCoordinates(772, 1685);

   // Click Login Button on the same screen as I agree checkbox

   app.TapCoordinates(315, 1240);

   //Entering user name

   app.EnterText(e => e.Css("input#cwsUID"), "qaqa68");

   //Entering password

   app.EnterText(e => e.Css("input#cwsPwd"), "Harmony1");

   //Click Login button

   app.Tap(e => e.Css("input#submitButton"));

In the above script i want to delay execution between the steps. The problem is its executing the scripts when i ran on a device after the first line execution its trying to execute second line but till then the second page is not loaded so i have to stop execution till that next page is loaded or some MS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app.WaitForElement() and wait for an element that exists on the second page, and the test will pause until that page is loaded.

Comment: how can i do it? because all the elements i am getting using coordinates(first 4 commands) and all the elements are not having any id when i use repl(). This is the splash screen which will have next button for which am not getting any id using repl().                                                                                                     I went through documentation of wait for element which can be used with id, class, xpath but how can i wait for an element with coordinates?